How to render Styled text and/or Math formula written in text in Firestore database to App UI in Jetpack Compose?
this below is my code which is fetching data from firestore and i want some text or sentence to be bold or italic or underlined along with if there is math formula written in text in firestore i would like it to be also rendered in the app UI or if any images present also to  be rendered.

I tried but could include all three of them to render and i were only able to do text styling and not the math formula rendering.
@Composable
fun QuestionCard(questionText: String) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(8.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(containerColor = Color.Transparent)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = questionText,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineSmall,
            fontWeight = Bold,
            fontSize = 18.sp,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
        )
    }
}

// Option card with feedback colors
@Composable
fun OptionCard(
    optionText: String,
    isSelected: Boolean,
    isCorrect: Boolean,
    showCorrectAnswer: Boolean,
    disabled: Boolean,
    onSelect: () -> Unit
) {
    val backgroundColor = when {
        isSelected && isCorrect -> AppColors.OptionGreen
        isSelected && !isCorrect -> AppColors.OptionRed
        showCorrectAnswer && isCorrect -> AppColors.OptionGreen
        else -> Color.White
    }
    val radioColors = RadioButtonDefaults.colors(disabledSelectedColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary)

    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(4.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .clickable(enabled = !disabled) { onSelect() },
        colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(containerColor = backgroundColor),
        elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(5.dp)
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(12.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterStart // Align content to the start
        ) {
            Row(
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            ) {
                RadioButton(
                    selected = isSelected,
                    onClick = onSelect,
                    enabled = !disabled,
                    colors = radioColors,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(start = if (isSelected || (showCorrectAnswer && isCorrect)) 16.dp else 16.dp)
                )

                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))

                Text(
                    text = optionText,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge,
                    modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                    maxLines = Int.MAX_VALUE
                )
            }

            // Show Check/Close icon on top
            if (isSelected || (showCorrectAnswer && isCorrect)) {
                val icon = if (isCorrect) Icons.Default.Check else Icons.Default.Close
                val iconColor = if (isCorrect) AppColors.CorrectGreen else AppColors.IncorrectRed
                Icon(
                    imageVector = icon,
                    contentDescription = null,
                    tint = iconColor,
                    modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp).padding(start = 4.dp)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
@Composable
fun ExplanationButton(
    explanation: String,
    showExplanation: Boolean,
    onToggleExplanation: () -> Unit,
    currentQuestionState: MCQViewModel.QuestionState
) {
    if (currentQuestionState.hasAnswered) {
        Button(
            onClick = onToggleExplanation,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
            enabled = currentQuestionState.hasAnswered
        ) {
            Text("Explanation")
        }

        if (showExplanation) {
            Text(
                text = explanation,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(12.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}


i was expecting to see when the styled text or math formula are in between the sentences of lets say questionText field in firestore in text but when i tried i would only show the styled word like a word in italic while all the remaining normal text did not show
